# how to override a base class method called from a constructor

Tags: c#, class, inheritance

I'm probably doing this totally wrong..

```
public class BaseClass
{
  public string result { get; set; }

  public BaseClass(){}
  public BaseClass(string x) {
    result = doThing(x);
  }
  public virtual string doThing(string x)
  {
     return x;
  }
}



public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{

  public DerivedClass(){}
  public DerivedClass(string x):base(x){}
  public override string doThing(string x)
  {
     return "override" + x;
  }
}
```

I'd like for a new DerivedClass("test") to have a result of "overridetest" but it doesn't: it calls the base method of doThing. Am I missing something? Do I need to make an AbstractClass and have both BaseClass and DerivedClass inherit from that, Derived class also overriding methods?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling virtual method in base class constructor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448258/calling-virtual-method-in-base-class-constructor)

Comment: its not quite a duplicate - that was todo with validity of ste, in my case the derived doThing is never called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are making a virtual call in the constructor. The mechanics of this issue and possible workarounds are detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119506/virtual-member-call-in-a-constructor).

In short, the overridden function has not yet been constructed when you enter the constructor of the base class, therefore the virtual function in the base class is called.

Comment: In the posted code, the overridden function **is** available when the control is in the base class' constructor as a result of static compiler binding. The derived class' method does not get called because you cannot access any derived class' nonstatic member from a base class.

Answer (score 2):

You can't access a subclass' instance member from a base class.

It calls the base class's `doThing` method because that is the only available `doThing` method as far as the base class is concerned. If you want an instance of each class call it's own `doThing` method, in your child class replace:

```
public DerivedClass(string x):base(x){}
```

with:

```
public DerivedClass(string x)
{
    doThing(x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From a design perspective, you should always be wary of "doing things" during a constructor call. The purpose of a constructor is merely to get an instance of the class into a valid state for future use; it shouldn't try to "do" anything else or have any other side effects. If your object construction is a complicated affair, you might want to employ the Builder or Factory patterns to shield calling code from the complexity.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your `DerivedClass` uses the base constructor and will set `result` as `base.doThing("test")` which is "test".

so you could change your `DerivedClass` to:

```
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{

  public DerivedClass(){}
  public DerivedClass(string x):base(x)
  {
     result="override"+x; 
     //or as result already be set as x, you can use: result="override" + result;
  }

}
```

or as you said,

> need to make an AbstractClass and have both BaseClass and
>   DerivedClass inherit from that, Derived class also overriding methods?